# HDFS: move multiple files using Java / Scala API

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, hdfs

I need to move multiple files in HDFS, that correspond to a given regular expression, using a Java / Scala program. For example, I have to move all files with name `*.xml` from folder `a` to folder `b`.

Using a shell command I can use the following:

```
bin/hdfs dfs -mv a/*.xml b/
```

I can move a single file using Java API, with the following code (scala language), using the `rename` method on `FileSystem` class:

```
// Prepare initial configuration
val conf = new Configuration()
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://hdfs:9000/user/root")
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
// Move a single file
val ok = fs.rename(new Path("a/file.xml"), new Path("b/file.xml"));
```

As far as I know the [`Path`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.html) class represents an URI. Then, I can't use in the following way:

```
val ok = fs.rename(new Path("a/*.xml"), new Path("b/"));
```

Is there a way to move a set of file in HDFS via Java / Scala API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fs.rename(new Path("a"), new Path("b"))`

But if you want to have `*.xml` there are filter files like globfilter.

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(arg0[0]), conf);
Path path = new Path(arg0[0] + arg0[1]); // arg0[1] NYSE_201[2-3]
//arg0[0] is base path
//ar0[1] uses regular expression

FileStatus[] status = fs.globStatus(path);
Path[] paths = FileUtil.stat2Paths(status);
for (Path p : paths) {
    // <loops all the source paths>
    // <need to implement logic to rename the paths using fs.rename>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Another method to achive what I need is to use the method `listStatus` that accept a `Path` and a `PathFilter`, that allows you to filter the results of the listing.

Comment: Where can we find the list of commands that we can execute using fs? Any pointers, Like fs.rename fs.globStatus and more. Thanks in advance

Comment: Am I looking at the right link [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html)  ?